# How to get the font face size and formatting of a native element in Android application?

Tags: android, view, android-styles

I would like to reuse the exact same font-face etc... like Android uses in the PreferenceScreen

Here is a screenshot I am looking to reuse the title, and the summary style from these views.

[alt text http://www.eyeonweb.com/android/images/l2.png](http://www.eyeonweb.com/android/images/l2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use system-defined text appearances like `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge` (also Small, Medium).

For more on these system-defined attributes, see:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html

There's also the [`hierarchyviewer`](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html) tool that is bundled with the SDK, which will let you inspect views and their attributes from any running app.